# How to only display part of content in JTextField in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I have a JTextField in a cell of a JTable. It will read a long string, but I need only some key string in the long string show on JTextField. And I also need use the whole long string to output by call tableModel.getValueAt(...)
how to do that?

BTW: I insert a row which contain the long string by tableModel.addRow(vec), the string is added to vecter

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand the question. The default renderer is a JLabel (not a JTextField) and if the string is too long to display in a cell then "..." is displayed when the text is truncated. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks and I have solved my problem. Just override getTableCellRendererComponent method and process what I need